# Mobile Phone Provider While In Curacao and Saint Martin

Tags: cellphones, caribbean

Is there a provider that I can use in Curacao and Satin Martin? Verizon claims that they have coverage in Curacao on CDMA but thats not true. Do any of the providers support the European GSM frequencies? [I have an unlocked Euro dual band phone]

I would prefer if:

1. It was inexpensive
2. Could call the US cheaply.

Comment: Saint-Martin, Sint Maarten or both? (I'm not sure if both halves of the island have the same phone providers or not)

Comment: Saint-Martin. I'll be on the french side

Answer (score 3):

[UTS](http://www.uts.cw/personal/chippie/chippieland) (previously Setel) looks like an option - single prepaid account for Curaçao, St. Maarten / French St. Martin, and others.

It appears that [Curaçao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Americas) at least uses GSM 900 for 2G (like Europe), and [other sources](http://www.wireless.att.com/travelguide/coverage/coverage_details.jsp?CIDL=1108&MNC=CING) say St Martin do as well.

No idea on the call costs.